# Excel crashes when saved as CSV file a second time

Tags: excel, vba, csv, crash, save

When I run the code for first time, it replaces the existing document and saves the CSV file with no problem. But when I run the code a second time, Excel crashes when save the CSV.

I have a workaround, after running the code for first time re-opening Excel, but it takes too much time, any ideas?

```
Sub copiar_ayuda1()
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  With Sheets("input11")
    .Select
    .Move
  End With
  PathName = "" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "os.csv"

  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=PathName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
  ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do ? is it to save `Sheets("input11")` as `CSV` file format ?

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Which instruction causes it? Your question is incomplete, please [edit] - wait no, there's no error, is there? So the code works but it's just slow? Can you please clarify your post?

Comment: Ok. I have an excel and I want to save as CSV format the sheet ("input11"). And I ran the code for first time with no problem and the  CSV created replaced the existing one. And when I ran it a second time, excel crashed: "Microsoft excel has stopping working". It happened when I saved the new CSV file replacing the old file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to save `Sheets("input11")` as "CSV" file, all you need to do is:

```
Option Explicit

Sub copiar_ayuda1()

Dim PathName As String
Dim Sht As Worksheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

PathName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\os.csv"

Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("input11")
With Sht
    .SaveAs Filename:=PathName, _
    FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: @Diego Bauza  have you tried the code above ? is it working as you intended ?

Comment: Thanks for answer. It is not working as I intended. It replace the name of the sheet "input11" to "os" and save the entire original file in CSV format with the name "os".